# Browserify tries to find module on a bad path

Tags: node.js, browserify

I'm trying to make a browser-side Imgur module, but the imgur module on NPM has some problems with requiring another module.

`Error: Cannot find module './C:/Users/*******/AppData/Local/Yarn/config/global/node_modules/is-buffer/index.js' from 'D:\Projects\********\node_modules\http-signature\lib'`

As you can see, it's trying to get a module from `./C:/...`, but since there's no `C:` directory in the CWD, it can't find anything.

Is it possible to fix this?

Comment: Did you created a **package.josn** file for your project? Did you installed all dependencies of used mudules? `npm i`

Comment: @sultan the problem is not with dependencies, it's with browserify's path handling

Comment: When do you get this error? When you run a certain function or when you start the app?

Comment: @db2791 When I bundle w/ browserify.

Comment: Can we see the command you're running that gives you this error? Or if you're doing this programmatically, the code which triggers it?

Comment: Can you please create a minimal reproducible repo that we can use? This should have the exact package.json that you use so any dependency issue could be looked into

Answer (score 1):

People have reported a similar problem in [this bug](https://github.com/browserify/browserify/issues/1531), which you may be caught in.

[Fortunately it was fixed very recently.](https://github.com/browserify/browserify/issues/1531#issuecomment-369299900) Run `npm update` to grab the Browserify dependency `insert-module-globals@7.0.2` or later, which should contain the fix.

Comment: Sadly, it was not a problem with insert-module-globals.

Comment: @skiilaa Have you resolved the issue? If not post the code / commands you're using and we can help you better.

Comment: `browserify index.js -o bundle.js` is the command. The problem is still present.

Comment: @skiilaa Out of curiousity, are you using *both* Yarn and npm? Can you verify that `is-buffer/index.js` actually exists? I'm wondering if that relative-drive syntax is actually interpreted correctly somewhere in the stack.

Comment: I am using both Yarn and NPM, and is-buffer/index.js exists.

Comment: Perhaps try installing everything with one or the other, including global packages. Maybe there's a conflict with the way they're working together -- It seems like this npm package is referencing a global yarn one.